# save dataframe with lists in one column as tab separated single entries ".txt" file

Tags: r

I have following dataframe in R:

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(rowname = c("1", "2", "3"), col1 = c("A B", "A B C D", 
"C D E")), .Names = c("rowname", "col1"), row.names = c(NA, 3L
), class = "data.frame")
```

the second column contains lists of different length. I want to save it in a form of ".txt" file where every element of a list is tab separated. Output should look like this:

```
1 A B
2 A B C D
3 C D E
```

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Can you be more specific with the provided data and your requirement? For instance, the data frame you provided, have varying length and hence will generate NAs.

Comment: Ok if you've solved it, please post it an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved by first collapsing the list:

```
for (i in 1:dim(df)[1]){
   df$col1[i] <- paste(unlist(df$col1[i]), collapse = "\t")
}
df$col1 <- unlist(df$col1)
```

and then saving table

```
write.table(df, file = file, quote = F, sep = "\t")
```